# vector subtraction to move game object to another object location on unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

hello I'm new to unity and game development in general, I have this task that requires me to move an object through vectors addition and subtraction, it is really simple and i understand the math behind it but I just cant understand how to use gameobject.find and transform.position of the object that has the script on it in the code.

this here is the task im trying to do :
Create two new GameObjects and position them some distance apart from each other (preferably they should have different Meshes so you can tell them apart).

Create a new script and attach it to one of the GameObjects
In this new script, make it so it can do this :

1-Find position of the other GameObject (you can use GameObject.Find to do this)

2-Use the other GameObject position and the position of itself (transform.position) to determine a direction from its position to the other GameObject.

3-Apply this direction to the transform.position of this object, so that it will immediately move to the position of the other object (this will happen in a single frame and as such appear to have “teleported”, but this is fine for now)

4-Make it so this happens on a Key Press

and this is the code I have written:

```
    
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyVector3 : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject sphere;
  private float x, y, z;

    public MyVector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

public MyVector3 SubVectors(MyVector3 P, MyVector3 G)
    {
        MyVector3 rv = new MyVector3(0, 0, 0);
        rv.x = P.x - G.x;
        rv.y = P.y - G.y;
        rv.z = P.z - G.z;
        return rv;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        MyVector3 P = new MyVector3(transform.position);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? It pretty much seems like it. Sounds like you can simply do `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCoe.Space)){ otherObject.transform.position = transform.position;` ... I don't see why you would be over complicating things ... `Vector3` already is a type provided by Unity .. why re-implement it? And why as a `MonoBehaviour` which are not allowed to have a constructor nor be crated using `new` ...

Answer (score 0):

> 1-Find position of the other GameObject (you can use GameObject.Find to do this)

In your component, use transform.position.

> 2-Use the other GameObject position and the position of itself (transform.position) to determine a direction from its position to the other GameObject.

Assuming you created a reference to your gameobject :

```
public GameObject otherGameObject;
```

You can do something like this :

```
var direction = otherGameObject.transform.position - transform.position;
```

> 3-Apply this direction to the transform.position of this object, so that it will immediately move to the position of the other object (this will happen in a single frame and as such appear to have “teleported”, but this is fine for now)

To avoid teleportation, multiply your direction by Time.deltaTime
Doc to Time.deltaTime : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

> 4-Make it so this happens on a Key Press

Google is your friend :)
You'll find references to the old input system and new input system.
If you are new, I suggest you to use the old one since it is easier to learn and use.
See this tutorial as example : https://medium.com/geekculture/setting-up-the-legacy-input-system-in-unity-b4d685ca6150